# Azure Shared Access Signature (SAS) with client tool (Cloudberry or Azure Storage Explorer)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, cloudberry

After generating SAS for an Azure Storage Container, when using it in Cloudberry or Azure Storage explorer tool, a base64 error is shown.

My question is can a Shared Access Signature for a container be used in client tools like Cloudberry or Azure Storage explorer?

Answer (score 2):

No. AFAIK, all the client tools today support managing storage accounts using account name/key with the exception of [`ClumsyLeaf CloudXplorer`](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer). You can give that a try.

Comment: Awesome Gaurav, you really deserve an Azure Storage MVP. I would like to see a blog post (on cloudportam.com?) why Azure cloud storage explorer providers do not offer SAS for more fine-granular access stories

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, SAS connection is also supported by [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

If anyone trying to solve 'ACL on azure storage' in your company without having full Azure AD - for now you're just going to have to get inventive with managing those connection keys, but this platform keeps evolving so keep an eye on the space.

[image: lots of options for azure storage connections]